# Manifest upload of multiple tiles to GEE and projection issues

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

I am trying to upload multiple tiles to Google Earth Engine using the manifest option:
`earthengine upload image --manifest manifest.json`

I am having issues into understanding and implementing the CRS and affine transformation options. Below a summary of what I tried.

I can not get the right combination of options for mosaiking together the tiles into one asset.

### 1. Upload a single tile

Manually (browser graphical interface) or using the manifest: no problems
See for example [this image](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/soilgrids-isric/phh2o_0-5cm_mean_tileSG-004-046_3-2)

### 2. Upload multiple tiles

#### Projection 4326

```
"crs" : "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]"
```

#### Manifest without affine transformation

```
"sources": [
        {
          "uris": [
            "gs://sg20-upload-gee/phh2o_0-5cm_mean_tileSG-004-046_1-3.tif"
          ]
        },
        {
          "uris": [
            "gs://sg20-upload-gee/phh2o_0-5cm_mean_tileSG-004-046_3-2.tif"
          ]
        }
      ]
```

- Error:
  `FAILED     Affine mismatch: found AffineTransform[[0.004193911810302, 0.0, -7.424748120676926], [0.0, -0.004193911810302, 58.51536655102318]] in phh2o_0-5cm_mean_tileSG-004-046_3-2.tif, previously saw AffineTransform[[0.004696413740213, 0.0, -7.912014673168407], [0.0, -0.004696413740213, 62.38737075514959]]. Difference in X scale exceeds 8.673617379884035E-13.`

#### Manifest with affine transformation

The parameters were obtained from python gdal `GetGeoTransform()`

```
      "sources": [
        {
          "uris": [
            "gs://sg20-upload-gee/phh2o_0-5cm_mean_tileSG-004-046_1-3.tif"
          ]
          "affine_transform": {
            "scale_x": 0.0046964137402130185,
            "shear_x": 0.0,
            "translate_x": -7.912014673168407,
            "shear_y": 0.0,
            "scale_y": -0.0046964137402130185,
            "translate_y": 62.38737075514959
          }
        },
        {
          "uris": [
            "gs://sg20-upload-gee/phh2o_0-5cm_mean_tileSG-004-046_3-2.tif"
          ],
          "affine_transform": {
            "scale_x": 0.004193911810301575,
            "shear_x": 0.0,
            "translate_x": -7.424748120676926,
            "shear_y": 0.0,
            "scale_y": -0.004193911810301575,
            "translate_y": 58.51536655102318
          }
        }
      ]
```

- Error:
  `FAILED     Affine mismatch: found AffineTransform[[0.004193911810302, 0.0, -7.424748120676926], [0.0, -0.004193911810302, 58.51536655102318]] in phh2o_0-5cm_mean_tileSG-004-046_3-2.tif, previously saw AffineTransform[[0.004696413740213, 0.0, -7.912014673168407], [0.0, -0.004696413740213, 62.38737075514959]]. Difference in X scale exceeds 8.673617379884035E-13.`

The same happens with `scale_x` and `scale_y` set at 1.0

#### Manifest without CRS or affine transformation

- Error:
  `FAILED     Affine mismatch: found AffineTransform[[0.004193911810302, 0.0, -7.424748120676926], [0.0, -0.004193911810302, 58.51536655102318]] in phh2o_0-5cm_mean_tileSG-004-046_3-2.tif, previously saw AffineTransform[[0.004696413740213, 0.0, -7.912014673168407], [0.0, -0.004696413740213, 62.38737075514959]]. Difference in X scale exceeds 8.673617379884035E-13.`

### GDAL info of the two tiles

#### Tile 1

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ./upld/phh2o_0-5cm_mean_tileSG-004-046_1-3.tif
Size is 504, 212
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-7.912014673168407,62.387370755149590)
Pixel Size = (0.004696413740213,-0.004696413740213)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -7.9120147,  62.3873708) (  7d54'43.25"W, 62d23'14.53"N)
Lower Left  (  -7.9120147,  61.3917310) (  7d54'43.25"W, 61d23'30.23"N)
Upper Right (  -5.5450221,  62.3873708) (  5d32'42.08"W, 62d23'14.53"N)
Lower Right (  -5.5450221,  61.3917310) (  5d32'42.08"W, 61d23'30.23"N)
Center      (  -6.7285184,  61.8895509) (  6d43'42.67"W, 61d53'22.38"N)
Band 1 Block=504x8 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768
```

#### Tile 2

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ./upld/phh2o_0-5cm_mean_tileSG-004-046_3-2.tif
Size is 496, 113
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-7.424748120676926,58.515366551023178)
Pixel Size = (0.004193911810302,-0.004193911810302)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -7.4247481,  58.5153666) (  7d25'29.09"W, 58d30'55.32"N)
Lower Left  (  -7.4247481,  58.0414545) (  7d25'29.09"W, 58d 2'29.24"N)
Upper Right (  -5.3445679,  58.5153666) (  5d20'40.44"W, 58d30'55.32"N)
Lower Right (  -5.3445679,  58.0414545) (  5d20'40.44"W, 58d 2'29.24"N)
Center      (  -6.3846580,  58.2784105) (  6d23' 4.77"W, 58d16'42.28"N)
Band 1 Block=496x8 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768
```

Comment: Did you try setting the parameters for the affine transformation with the same values for both images?

Comment: Not yet. It is a good suggestion. I will try next and report here.

Answer (score 2):

Manifest uploads get merged into a single image that at the end, can only have 1 scale.  So you can't upload multiple pieces that have different scales.  If your files have different scale, your only option is to upload them into a collection and use a mosaic() of that collection.   Everything will get reprojected on use into whatever output coordinate system you specify.

Comment: Thanks! This helps explaining the problem